# How to fix R Studio to stop pressing Space Bar to complete each word?

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I am using R Studio 1.2.5042 on Mac OS. As I type each word out into the Script section, I have to press Space Bar or Tab at the end of each word to finish that word and move onto the next. As I type each word, R Script only displays the first letter of whatever it is I am typing. This is a very annoying problem for me because I can't really see what I'm typing and having to press Space Bar too many times.

Did anyone encounter the same issue and have found a fix?

Comment: Maybe a better question for the RStudio support site: https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: Clicking on insert key in the keyboard may solve your problem.

Comment: I don't have an insert key on my keyboard since it's a Mac laptop. Is there anywhere else I can try to click/press?